# Probability of getting a two pair with an ace as last card

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

What's the probability of getting a two pair(2 pairs of similar cards) in a 5 hand with the last card being Ace. An example would be 2 6's, 2 3's, and an ace.

I tried,

$$
\frac{13 \cdot \binom{4}{2} \cdot 12 \cdot \binom{4}{2} \cdot 1 \cdot ?? }{\binom{52}{5}}
$$

What would be the count of ace there? I thought $\binom{4}{2}$ but we might have already taken ace in while choosing previous cards.

Comment: You need $\binom{12}{2}$ for the ranks of the two pairs.

Comment: @Ch3steR: you were a bit quick to accept. See much shorter answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities here, depending on whether the hand includes a pair of aces:

1. There are two non-ace pairs among the first four cards drawn, then an ace is drawn with the fifth card.
2. There is one non-ace pair, one ace, and one card of another rank among the first four cards, then an ace is drawn with the fifth card.

*Two non-ace pairs among the first four cards drawn, then an ace is drawn with the fifth card*: We have to multiply the probability of obtaining two non-ace pairs among the first four cards by the probability of drawing an ace with the fifth card.

There are $\binom{52}{4}$ ways to select four cards from the deck.  There are $\binom{12}{2}$ ways of selecting the two non-ace ranks from which the pairs are drawn and $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to draw two of the four cards for each of those ranks.  Hence, the probability of drawing two pairs among the first four cards is
$$\frac{\dbinom{12}{2}\dbinom{4}{2}^2}{\dbinom{52}{4}}$$
Since all four aces are among the $48$ cards remaining in the deck, the probability of drawing an ace with the fifth card is
$$\frac{4}{48} = \frac{1}{12}$$
Hence, the probability that this case occurs is
$$\frac{\dbinom{12}{2}\dbinom{4}{2}^2}{\dbinom{52}{4}} \cdot \frac{1}{12}$$

*One non-ace pair, one ace, and one card of another rank among the first four cards, then an ace is drawn with the fifth card*:  We have to multiply the probability of obtaining one non-ace pair, one ace, and one card of another rank among the first four cards by the probability of then obtaining an ace with the fifth card.

There are $12$ ways to pick the rank of the pair, $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to select two cards of that rank, $4$ ways to pick the first ace, $11$ ways to pick the rank of the other card among the first four cards, and four ways to select a card from that rank.  Thus, the probability of drawing one non-ace pair, one ace, and one card of another rank among the first four cards is
$$\frac{\dbinom{12}{1}\dbinom{4}{2}\dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{11}{1}\dbinom{4}{1}}{\dbinom{52}{4}}$$
Since exactly one ace is drawn among the first four cards, there are three aces left among the remaining $48$ cards in the deck. Thus, the probability of drawing an ace with the fifth card is
$$\frac{3}{48} = \frac{1}{16}$$
Hence, the probability that this case occurs is
$$\frac{\dbinom{12}{1}\dbinom{4}{2}\dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{11}{1}\dbinom{4}{1}}{\dbinom{52}{4}} \cdot \frac{1}{16}$$

Since these two cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the desired probability can be obtained by adding the above probabilities.

Comment: FYI, the answer can be written much shorter. See mine below.

Comment: Your denominator should be $52 \choose 5$!

Answer (score 2):

You want the probability of drawing an ace as the fifth card, times the *conditional* probability, when given that will happen, that among the drawing of the *first* four cards gives two non-ace pairs, *or* a non-ace pair, a non-ace of another rank, and an ace to pair with the fifth ace.$$\tfrac{\tbinom 41}{\tbinom{52}1}\cdot\tfrac{\tbinom{12}{2}\tbinom 42^2+\tbinom{12}{1}\tbinom 42\tbinom{11}1\tbinom41\tbinom 31}{\tbinom{51}{4}}=\dfrac{2376}{270725}$$

PS: This assumes triples do not count as pairs.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that the pairs must be different and neither can include an ace, because otherwise you have 4 of a kind or a full house.

Start by looking at the first 4 cards. To find the number of favorable deals (in order) you can choose any of 48 cards for the 1st, 3 for the 2nd, 44 for the 3rd, and 3 for the 4th. If B is the first card the pairs can be arranged as BBCC, BCBC or BCCB, so multiply by 3. This gives $$48\times3\times44\times3\times3$$ favorable ways of dealing the 4 cards (in order). The total number of ways of dealing the 4 cards in order is $$52 \times51\times50\times49$$ so the probability of getting two non-ace pairs in the first 4 cards is $$\frac{48\times3\times44\times3\times3}{52 \times51\times50\times49}$$ The probability of an ace for the last card then is 4/48, so the answer is $$\frac{48\times3\times44\times3\times3}{52 \times51\times50\times49}\times\frac{4}{48}$$

Answer (score -1):

Shorter answer.

There are ${12 \choose 2}$ ways of choosing two ranks that make the two pair (excluding aces). For each of the pairs, there are ${4 \choose 2}$ ways of choosing the suit. There is one way of choosing the rank of an ace out of the remaining 11 rank choices (${11 \choose 1}$  with probability $\frac{1}{11}$), and there are ${4 \choose 1}$ ways of choosing an ace out of the suits.

So the probability is:

$$
\frac{{12 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}^2 \times 4}{52 \choose 5}
$$

Comment: You overlooked the case where one of the pairs is a pair of aces.  Besides, your calculation of the other case is wrong.

Comment: I discount the case of choosing an ace as a pair card from the start. I checked numerically. Both our results are the same, too! Assuming you meant to write the denominator as $52 \choose 5$. You wrote $52 \choose 4$.

Comment: For each pair, there are two cards drawn from that rank, not one.  Also, you have not taken into account that the aces must be the fifth card drawn.

Comment: By definition, pairs are of the *same* rank, so one rank for each of the two pair. I am counting ranks not cards.

Comment: And, as I said, once you correct the denominator in your answer the result is exactly the same! Just check it!

Comment: You need to choose two suits for each of the pairs and one suit for the ace.

Comment: @DanielMathias: Thanks. Edited.